# "cannot find symbol: variable input" error

Tags: java

Here is the code where I'm having trouble:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Game {
public static final int ROCK = 1;
public static final int PAPER = 2;
public static final int SCISSORS = 3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = intro();
    int numRounds = numRounds(name);
    game(name, numRounds);
}

public static String intro() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors. I, the computer, will be your opponent.");
    System.out.print("Please type in your name and press return: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    return name;
}

public static int numRounds(String name) {
    System.out.println("Welcome " + name + ".");
    System.out.println("All right " + name + ". How many games would you like to play?");
    System.out.print("Enter the number of rounds you want to play and press return: ");
    int numRounds = input.nextInt();
    return numRounds;
}
```

When I use the scanner to get the values for the user's name and number of rounds they'd like to play, I get the error. I just want to return these values for use in the main function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where's the implementation of the `game` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `input` variable in the two methods that you want it - pass it as a methhod argument:

```
public static String intro(Scanner input) { .. }
public static int numRounds(String name, Scanner input) { .. }
```

...

```
String name = intro(input);
int numRounds = numRounds(name, input);
```

Apart from that, there is no `game()` method - define it.

Comment: i have the game method, i just didn't post it here, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty, but I think this line:

```
String name = input.nextLine();
```

Tries to use the variable `input`, but that's not in its scope: it cannot "reach" it, so its not an initialised variable.

Either put this in that function:

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Or make `input` "global" by declaring it as a for instance `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `intro()` and `numRounds()` methods are referencing `input` which is not visible to it.  Try passing it in as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`input` is declared inside the `main()` method, so it doesn't exist outside that method. You should declare it as a class variable, outside the `main()` method, so that `intro()` has access to it.